# CSS Friendly and upgrade to ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, css, .net-4.0, browser-detection

I just upgraded one of our web apps to ASP.NET 4.0.  It is using CssFriendly for the Menu and a few pages that have Trees on them.  When I try to run on my local machine (Win7 x64, IIS7) I am getting:

> error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The browser or
>   gateway element with ID
>   'MozillaFirefox' cannot be found.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 7:    </browser>
>   Line 8:
>   Line 9:    <browser refID="MozillaFirefox">
>   Line 10:     <controlAdapters>
>   Line 11:       <adapter> controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
>
> Source File:
>   E:\RivWorks\localhost\App_Browsers\CSSMenuAdapter.browser
>
> Version Information:
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

I browsed for some solutions and followed the directions at [http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770145) under the “Browser Definition Files Updated“ heading.  If I run ASPNET_REGBROWSERS in the command window in VS2010 I get:

> aspnet_regbrowsers –i
>   Command "aspnet_regbrowsers" is not valid.

So I tried it from the command prompt (in admin mode) and it seemed to work.  I then recompiled my app and republished it.  I am still getting the same error.  Any ideas what I am missing?

---

NOTE 1:
In my CSSMenuAdapter.browser file (CSS Friendly) there is an entry:

```
 <browser refID="MozillaFirefox">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
               adapterType="RivWorks.Web.MenuAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
```

In C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers\mozilla.browser there is:

```
<browser id="MozillaFirefox" parentID="MozillaRV">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="Gecko\/\d+ Firefox\/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.[.\d]*))" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="browser"                         value="Firefox" />
        <capability name="majorversion"                    value="${major}" />
        <capability name="minorversion"                    value="${minor}" />
        <capability name="version"                         value="${version}" />
        <capability name="type"                            value="Firefox${version}" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```

I am not understanding why it cannot be found.  :(

---

NOTE 2:  I commented out the browser element in the CSSMenuAdapter.browser file and the site is working again.  I looked at the code that was generated and it looks good in Chrome.  I also looked at it in Firefox and it is working (scratching my head on that one as it is commented out).  And IE is working as well.  I am so lost as to what is really broken here now!

Comment: Before executing the aspnet_regbrowsers command, did you copy the browsers config files into the .net 4.0 folder?

Comment: I copied the 2.0 browser files (Old Browser Definition Files folder).  Since CssFriendly was written for 2.0 (3.0/3.5 included as the browser definitions were all 2.0) I was thinking that should fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update refID to just "Firefox". that worked for me because in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers\mozilla.browser
Id is Firefox not MozillaFirefox.